# I can't install or uninstall through Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-installation, software-center, uninstall

I recently tried updating chrome and realized that I couldn't install or uninstall any software through Ubuntu Software Center. As soon as I try to open it , I get
[this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXzVa.png). I clicked repair and then entered my password and got to [this window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmRI0.png)

Details:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 298492 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openarena-081-players_0.8.5split-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking openarena-081-players (0.8.5split-2) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: incorrect data check'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openarena-081-players_0.8.5split-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openarena-081-players_0.8.5split-2_all.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openarena-data:
 openarena-data depends on openarena-081-players; however:
  Package openarena-081-players is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package openarena-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openarena:
 openarena depends on openarena-081-players; however:
  Package openarena-081-players is not installed.
 openarena depends on openarena-data (>= 0.8.5-3~); however:
  Package openarena-data is not configured yet.
 openarena depends on openarena-data (<< 0.8.6~); however:
  Package openarena-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openarena (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Also, when I tried to download things straight from Ubuntu software center, I got a window saying that I couldn't install the things until I uninstalled Open Arena and openarena-data. I can't uninstall those things, however, because, ya know, I can't uninstall anything.

Answer (score 0):

The software center has always been bad.  I have no idea why they removed Synaptic

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

However, to install Chrome, you are best to use gdebi

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Right-click on the deb file and choose "open with"  gdebi.
All should be well .. make sure no other software managers are running at the same time.  Only one can install at a time.

Good Luck.
[image: gdebi]

[image]

Comment: I can't install synaptic or anything else..

Comment: I think you do not know what you are doing or do not have an internet connection.  show me the error.  you might need to use apt-get install instead of apt install if you are on a pre 16.04 release

Answer (score 0):

One of the packages that was downloaded is corrupt, hence the error:

```
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: incorrect data check'
```

To force it to be downloaded again you first need to remove the corrupt download from the local cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then update the list of available packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the missing packages:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And ensure all packages are properly configured:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```